# How to add 9 patch to this layout to make it like bubble chat?

Tags: java, android, layout

How to add 9 patch to this layout to make it like bubble chat ?   Here is my layout: **messaging_screen.xml**

http://pastebin.com/h9Dy5Pqz

Comment: you can't,  9 parch is a Drawable,  you can't add a Drawable to a layout file

Comment: You can add a drawable to a layout element, such as a TextView or even a ViewGroup.